# What is the reason behind this huge Performance difference in .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, performance, red-black-tree

I was just doing some research on RedBlack Tree. I knew that SortedSet class in .Net 4.0 uses RedBlack tree. So I took that part out as is using Reflector and created a RedBlackTree class. Now I am running some perf test on this RedBlackTree and SortedSet inserting 40000 sequential integral values (starting from 0 to 39999), I am astonished to see that there is huge perf difference as follows:

```
 RBTree    took 9.27208   sec to insert 40000 values 
 SortedSet took 0.0253097 sec to insert 40000 values
```

What is the reason behind it? BTW I ran the test in Release configuration only and here is the small test code

```
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            var rbT = new RedBlackTree<int>();      
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
            rbT.Add(i);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed);

        var ss = new SortedSet<int>();
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
            ss.Add(i);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed);
```

Edit

I would like to share the code also for RBTree what I've extracted so that you also can run the diagnostics

```
public class Node<T>
    {
        public Node(){}

        public Node(T value)
        {
            Item = value;
        }       

        public Node(T value, bool isRed)
        {
            Item = value;
            IsRed = isRed;
        }

        public T Item;
        public Node<T> Left;
        public Node<T> Right;
        public Node<T> Parent;
        public bool IsRed;
    }

    public class RedBlackTree<T>
    {
        public RedBlackTree(){} 

        public Node<T> root;
        int count, version; 
        Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;     

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (this.root == null)
            {
                this.root = new Node<T>(item, false);
                this.count = 1;
                this.version++;
                return;
            }

            Node<T> root = this.root;
            Node<T> node = null;
            Node<T> grandParent = null;
            Node<T> greatGrandParent = null;
            this.version++;

            int num = 0;
            while (root != null)
            {
                num = this.comparer.Compare(item, root.Item);
                if (num == 0)
                {
                    this.root.IsRed = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (Is4Node(root))
                {
                    Split4Node(root);
                    if (IsRed(node))
                    {
                        this.InsertionBalance(root, ref node, grandParent, greatGrandParent);
                    }
                }
                greatGrandParent = grandParent;
                grandParent = node;
                node = root;
                root = (num < 0) ? root.Left : root.Right;
            }
            Node<T> current = new Node<T>(item);
            if (num > 0)
            {
                node.Right = current;
            }
            else
            {
                node.Left = current;
            }
            if (node.IsRed)
            {
                this.InsertionBalance(current, ref node, grandParent, greatGrandParent);
            }
            this.root.IsRed = false;
            this.count++;
        }


        private static bool IsRed(Node<T> node)
        {
            return ((node != null) && node.IsRed);
        }

        private static bool Is4Node(Node<T> node)
        {
            return (IsRed(node.Left) && IsRed(node.Right));
        }

        private static void Split4Node(Node<T> node)
        {
            node.IsRed = true;
            node.Left.IsRed = false;
            node.Right.IsRed = false;
        }

        private void InsertionBalance(Node<T> current, ref Node<T> parent, Node<T> grandParent, Node<T> greatGrandParent)
        {
            Node<T> node;
            bool flag = grandParent.Right == parent;
            bool flag2 = parent.Right == current;
            if (flag == flag2)
            {
                node = flag2 ? RotateLeft(grandParent) : RotateRight(grandParent);
            }
            else
            {
                node = flag2 ? RotateLeftRight(grandParent) : RotateRightLeft(grandParent);
                parent = greatGrandParent;
            }
            grandParent.IsRed = true;
            node.IsRed = false;
            ReplaceChildOfNodeOrRoot(greatGrandParent, grandParent, node);
        }

        private static Node<T> RotateLeft(Node<T> node)
        {
            Node<T> right = node.Right;
            node.Right = right.Left;
            right.Left = node;
            return right;
        }

        private static Node<T> RotateRight(Node<T> node)
        {
            Node<T> left = node.Left;
            node.Left = left.Right;
            left.Right = node;
            return left;
        }

        private static Node<T> RotateLeftRight(Node<T> node)
        {
            Node<T> left = node.Left;
            Node<T> right = left.Right;
            node.Left = right.Right;
            right.Right = node;
            left.Right = right.Left;
            right.Left = left;
            return right;
        }

        private static Node<T> RotateRightLeft(Node<T> node)
        {
            Node<T> right = node.Right;
            Node<T> left = right.Left;
            node.Right = left.Left;
            left.Left = node;
            right.Left = left.Right;
            left.Right = right;
            return left;
        }

        private void ReplaceChildOfNodeOrRoot(Node<T> parent, Node<T> child, Node<T> newChild)
        {
            if (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent.Left == child)
                {
                    parent.Left = newChild;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Right = newChild;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.root = newChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Edit

---

I ran the same diagnostic on some other data structure (some created by me*, some from .net framework**) and here is the interesting results

```
*AATree                 00:00:00.0309294
*AVLTree                00:00:00.0129743
**SortedDictionary      00:00:00.0313571
*RBTree                 00:00:09.2414156
**SortedSet             00:00:00.0241973
```

RBTree is the same as above (stripped out from SortedSet class). **I tried with 400000 values also, but RBTree seems taking FOREVER**, I really don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to find out where your code spends the most time at?

Comment: When you say you "ran" the test in Release configuration - was that inside the debugger? or at a flat command prompt?

Comment: And you really copied the code, so it's running against itself?

Comment: Does this still occur if your code is executed in reverse order e.g. SortedSet first, followed by RBTree?

Comment: Ya, I run it from the flat command prompt.

Comment: I suspect the JIT. Run it in reverse order like ChrisBD says, or run it several times, not just once (I mean put the code in a loop so that it runs several times within the same program execution)

Comment: I ran the test in reverse order and in multiple iterations. But unfortunately the same results I am getting each time.

Comment: @Choco, if the JIT would take 9 seconds for this we wouldn't be using .NET

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a bug in your `Node<T>` class. When you call the constructor that only takes a single value argument you should be setting `IsRed` to `true`.

I suppose that the fixed `Node<T>` class should look something like this:

```
public sealed class Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRed { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Right { get; set; }

    public Node(T value)
    {
        Item = value;
        IsRed = true;
    }

    public Node(T value, bool isRed)
    {
        Item = value;
        IsRed = isRed;
    }
}
```

Another option -- my preference -- would be to omit that constructor altogether and always require `IsRed` to be set explicitly when you instantiate a new node:

```
public sealed class Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRed { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Right { get; set; }

    public Node(T value, bool isRed)
    {
        Item = value;
        IsRed = isRed;
    }
}
```

And then replace this line in your `Add` method...

```
Node<T> current = new Node<T>(item);
```

...with this...

```
Node<T> current = new Node<T>(item, true);
```

Comment: Oh! you the man. I just changed it and ran the diagnostic and guess what the respones time now is - 00.0204438 sec for the same set of data. Thanks a lot man, you save the day.

Comment: Brilliant. A lot including me were speculating about NGen, Reverse Order, compilation issues... and it appears it came from the code :)

Comment: in such cases, its hard to point out. cheaper (top off mind options) are always environment related. But IMO first the code should be checked in cases of such spectacular perf differences or other type of totally unexpected results. I have had similar experience and hitting at code and correcting code problem always set things right !!

Comment: This is also a very good example for Occam's Razor principle. "It states that among competing hypotheses, the hypothesis with the fewest assumptions should be selected."

Answer (score 3):

1. reverse the order of the tests and repeat the measurement.
2. randomize your data.  Sorted sets behave strangely when you insert pre-sorted data.

Comment: You are right! Randomize data give comparable results. The perf difference is negligible. But I am talking about a worst case scenario here. Why in this particular situation those two behave differently where SortedList is implemented by RBTree itself?

Comment: So they were 2 totally different algorithms. Another goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

SortedSet includes a [TargetedPatchingOptOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.targetedpatchingoptoutattribute.aspx) attribute, did your copied version include that?

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public bool Add(T item)
{
    return this.AddIfNotPresent(item);
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance. As of MSDN it

indicates that the .NET Framework class library method to which this attribute is applied is unlikely to be affected by servicing releases, and therefore is eligible to be inlined across Native Image Generator (NGen) images.

Comment: I doubt the performance difference is due to method inlining across Native Image Generator (NGen) images.

Comment: @Anindya Chatterjee - The methods are small, so inlining them can play a significant role in the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the difference wasn't that big I would suggest that the cause is that the .NET assemblies are NGen-ed and so they are already translated to native code. In the case of your class the time to compile the IL code into native code is amortized over the time of your test. How does increasing the number of loop iterations affect the times?